# Let $S=\{x\in(-\pi,\pi): x\ne 0,\pm\dfrac{\pi}{2}\}$. The sum of all distinct solutions of the following equation in the set $S$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $S=\{x\in(-\pi,\pi): x\ne 0,\pm\dfrac{\pi}{2}\}$. The sum of all distinct solutions of the equation 
$\sqrt{3}\sec x+\mathrm{cosec} x+2(\tan x-\cot x)=0$ in the set $S$ is equal to

My attempt is as follows:-

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\cos x}+\dfrac{1}{\sin x}+2\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)=0$$
$$\sqrt{3}\sin x+\cos x+2\sin x-2\cos x=0$$
$$\sin x(2+\sqrt{3})=\cos x$$
$$\tan x=\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\tan x=2-\sqrt{3}$$

$$x=\dfrac{\pi}{12},-\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{12}$$

So their sum would be $-\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{6}=-\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

But actual answer is $0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your second line should be $\sqrt3\sin x+\cos x+2\sin^2 x-2\cos^2x=0$ (note the squared terms).

Comment: thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

From the equatio $\sqrt3\sin x+\cos x+2\sin^2 x-2\cos^2x=0$, you van divide both sides by $2$, obtaining:
$$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin x+\frac{1}{2}\cos x+\sin^2 x-\cos^2x=0 \leftrightarrow \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x \leftrightarrow \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\cos(2x)$$
Now, the equation looks simplier and we can use the fact that:
$$\sin(\alpha)=\sin(\beta) \leftrightarrow \alpha -\beta=\pi+2k\pi \: \: \vee \: \: \alpha=\beta+2k\pi,  k \in Z$$
So, we have:
$$x+\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{2}-2x=\pi+2k\pi \leftrightarrow x=-\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi \vee x=\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{2}{3}k\pi$$
For $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$ the solutions are:
$$x=-\frac{5\pi}{9} \vee x=-\frac{\pi}{3} \vee x=\frac{\pi}{9} \vee x=\frac{7\pi}{9}$$
The sum is:
$$S=-\frac{5\pi}{9}-\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{7\pi}{9}=\frac{-5\pi-3\pi+\pi+7\pi}{9}=0$$

Your error has been committed in the second line $\sqrt3\sin x+\cos x+2\sin^2 x-2\cos^2x=0$ because you miss the square on $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.